# When I try to add user exception: The server is unwilling to process the request. and setPassword exception: thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, active-directory

I tried to do like below, get <del>"The server is unwilling to process the request." because this line `newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "userAccountControl", "512" });` I comment it, it's work but found new</del> exception "thrown by the target of an invocation" from this `newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { model.Password });`

Before that I use window server 2003R2(VM) to Active directory has no problem. Now I use window server 2012R2 has problem why?

```
     ConnectAD con = new ConnectAD();
                DirectoryEntry de = con.GetConnection();
                Utility ut = new Utility();

                using (DirectorySearcher searcher = new DirectorySearcher(de))
                {
                    searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", model.UserName);
                    using (SearchResultCollection resultUser = searcher.FindAll())
                    {
                        bool DoesExistUsesr = resultUser.Count > 0;
                        if (!DoesExistUsesr)
                        {//User doesn't exist
                            searcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=organizationalUnit)(ou={0}))", model.Group);
                            using (SearchResultCollection resultOU = searcher.FindAll())
                            {
                                bool DoesExistOU = resultOU.Count > 0;
                                if (DoesExistOU)
                                {//OU does exist
                                    de.Path = ut.SetChildPath("OU=" + model.Group);//"LDAP://" + Properties.Settings.Default.domainMyAD + "/" + "OU=" + model.Group + "," + Properties.Settings.Default.pathMyAD;
                                    DirectoryEntry newUser = de.Children.Add("CN=" + model.UserName, "user");
                                    newUser.Properties["displayName"].Value = model.Name + " " + model.Surname;
                                    newUser.Properties["givenName"].Value = model.Name;
                                    newUser.Properties["sn"].Value = model.Surname;
                                    newUser.Properties["mail"].Value = model.Email;
                                    newUser.Properties["department"].Value = model.Department;
                                    newUser.Properties["title"].Value = model.Title;
                                    newUser.Properties["userPrincipalName"].Value = model.UserName + "@" + Properties.Settings.Default.domainMyAD;
                                    newUser.Properties["sAMAccountname"].Value = model.UserName;
                                    newUser.Properties["PwdLastSet"].Value = -1;
                                    newUser.CommitChanges(); 
                                    newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", new object[] { model.Password }); //<-- ***thrown by the target of an invocation***
                                    newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "userAccountControl", "512" });
                                    newUser.CommitChanges();
                                }....
```

Thanks in advance.

Inner exception:The password does not meet the password policy requirements. Check the minimum password length, 
password complexity and password history requirements - Error Code : 800708c5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it. Inner exception about **password complexity**(uppercase, lowercase, length).
This case I test create account with password 123. I'm a newbie for AD :(

Answer (score 2):

You cannot enable an account (which is what setting userAccountControl to 512 does) that does not have a password. You have to do it after you save the new account.

But you also don't need to use Invoke to set the userAccountControl property. Try this, after the first CommitChanges:

```
...
//newUser.Invoke("Put", new object[] { "userAccountControl", "512" }); <-- Remove this
newUser.CommitChanges();
newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", model.Password);
newUser.Properties["userAccountControl"].Value = 512;
newUser.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: How so? It works perfectly in my code that's creating new accounts every day.

Comment: Exception "thrown by the target of an invocation" how to fix this.
I understand 512 to enable with password then exception "The server is unwilling to process the request."

Comment: Do not try to update userAccountControl before your first CommitChanges.

Comment: It's doesn't work, Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. setPassword line

Comment: I edit my code same as you it's doesn't work "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" on `newUser.Invoke("SetPassword", model.Password);` line